# Boost::stacktrace a specific thread

Tags: c++, boost

I want to debug an application where some threads seem to go into a deadlock situation in a production environment (I cannot debug, thus I need a meaningful log). I found boost::stacktrace::stacktrace(), but it dumps info for all threads.

Is it possible to limit the output to a specific thread?

Comment: Produce a dump, then load it into a debugger? We use Crashpad for this at work.

Comment: The application doesn't crash, thus I have no dump.

Comment: Kill the app manually. Since Crashpad is a separate process, it should produce the dump then.

Comment: Is there a problem about having "too much information"? Can't you e.g. also store the thread id/indicate which thread is involved?

Comment: I was thinking about adding a thread id, but didn't see where boost::stacktrace outputs the thread id/name.

Comment: Is it Linux specific?

Answer (score 0):

If it is Linux specific you can use `backtrace` and `backtrace_symbols` to retrieve the backtrace for that specific thread.

I  adapted this example from `man backtrace` to include a thread.

```cpp
       #include <execinfo.h>
       #include <stdio.h>
       #include <stdlib.h>
       #include <unistd.h>
       #include <thread>

       #define BT_BUF_SIZE 100

       void printbt(void)
       {
           int j, nptrs;
           void *buffer[BT_BUF_SIZE];
           char **strings;

           nptrs = backtrace(buffer, BT_BUF_SIZE);
           printf("backtrace() returned %d addresses\n", nptrs);

           /* The call backtrace_symbols_fd(buffer, nptrs, STDOUT_FILENO)
              would produce similar output to the following: */

           strings = backtrace_symbols(buffer, nptrs);
           if (strings == NULL) {
               perror("backtrace_symbols");
               exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
           }

           for (j = 0; j < nptrs; j++)
               printf("%s\n", strings[j]);

           free(strings);
       }

       static void myfunc2(void)
       {
           printbt();
       }

       void myfunc(int ncalls)
       {
           if (ncalls > 1)
               myfunc(ncalls - 1);
           else
               myfunc2();
       }

       int main(int argc, char *argv[])
       {
           if (argc != 2) {
               fprintf(stderr, "%s num-calls\n", argv[0]);
               return 0;
           }

           std::thread th( myfunc, atoi(argv[1]) );
           th.join();
       }
```

You have to compile with `-rdynamic` to work

```bash
$ g++ -g3 -rdynamic test2.cpp -o /tmp/test2 -lpthread
```

Running it provides

```
$ /tmp/test2 3

backtrace() returned 13 addresses
/tmp/test2(_Z7printbtv+0x32) [0x55e2dbe5d37b]
/tmp/test2(+0x4451) [0x55e2dbe5d451]
/tmp/test2(_Z6myfunci+0x29) [0x55e2dbe5d47d]
/tmp/test2(_Z6myfunci+0x22) [0x55e2dbe5d476]
/tmp/test2(_Z6myfunci+0x22) [0x55e2dbe5d476]
/tmp/test2(_ZSt13__invoke_implIvPFviEJiEET_St14__invoke_otherOT0_DpOT1_+0x36) [0x55e2dbe5e0af]
/tmp/test2(_ZSt8__invokeIPFviEJiEENSt15__invoke_resultIT_JDpT0_EE4typeEOS3_DpOS4_+0x4a) [0x55e2dbe5dffd]
/tmp/test2(_ZNSt6thread8_InvokerISt5tupleIJPFviEiEEE9_M_invokeIJLm0ELm1EEEEvSt12_Index_tupleIJXspT_EEE+0x47) [0x55e2dbe5df4d]
/tmp/test2(_ZNSt6thread8_InvokerISt5tupleIJPFviEiEEEclEv+0x2b) [0x55e2dbe5deef]
/tmp/test2(_ZNSt6thread11_State_implINS_8_InvokerISt5tupleIJPFviEiEEEEE6_M_runEv+0x20) [0x55e2dbe5dec0]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6(+0xd6de4) [0x7f306312ede4]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0x8609) [0x7f3063242609]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(clone+0x43) [0x7f3062f6a133]
```

You can use [__cxa_demangle](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/ext_demangling.html) to automatically demangle the symbols or you can simply use `c++filt` from gcc for that.

```bash
$ echo _ZSt13__invoke_implIvPFviEJiEET_St14__invoke_otherOT0_DpOT1_+0x36 | c++filt
void std::__invoke_impl<void, void (*)(int), int>(std::__invoke_other, void (*&&)(int), int&&)+0x36

$ echo _Z6myfunci+0x29 | c++filt
myfunc(int)+0x29
```

You can then go into gdb and look what line the offset `0x29` corresponds to inside the function `myfunc(int)`